# How to Escape dot(.) In a like expression in Oracle PL/SQL Statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

In a stored procedure I am filtering out list of employees whose role is SUPER.ADMIN

In such a case I used like expression as below

`Emp.Role_nm Like ''''||p_rolenm||''''`

- p_rolenm I have mentioned in stored procedure as VARCHAR2

When ever I pass a value to p_rolenm as SUPER.ADMIN it's throwing error as identifier SUPER.ADMIN is not declared.

How I can escape . (Dot) in PL/SQL statements?

Comment: It would help if you showed us more than just part of one statement.  Also, why use "LIKE" if you don't have any wildcard characters?

Answer (score 4):

Why do you use that many single quotes? You don't need any (at least, I think so):

Sample data:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, role varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test
  2  select 1, 'CLERK' from dual union all
  3  select 2, 'SUPER.ADMIN' from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID ROLE
---------- --------------------
         1 CLERK
         2 SUPER.ADMIN

SQL> set serveroutput on;
```

Procedure (anonymous, though, but that doesn't matter):

```
SQL> declare
  2    p_rolenm varchar2(20) := 'SUPER.ADMIN';
  3    l_id     number;
  4  begin
  5    select id into l_id
  6    from test
  7    where role = p_rolenm;
  8
  9    dbms_output.put_line('l_id = ' || l_id);
 10  end;
 11  /
l_id = 2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

If you need `like`, then

```
SQL> declare
  2    p_rolenm varchar2(20) := 'PER.ADM';            --> I changed this ...
  3    l_id     number;
  4  begin
  5    select id into l_id
  6    from test
  7    where role like '%' || p_rolenm || '%';        --> ... and this
  8
  9    dbms_output.put_line('l_id = ' || l_id);
 10  end;
 11  /
l_id = 2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

If you used dynamic SQL, then

```
SQL> declare
  2    p_rolenm varchar2(20) := 'PER.ADM';
  3    l_id     number;
  4    l_str    varchar2(200);                      --> new variable for execute immediate
  5  begin
  6    l_str := q'[select id from test where role like '%' || :a || '%']';
  7    execute immediate l_str into l_id using p_rolenm;
  8
  9    dbms_output.put_line('l_id = ' || l_id);
 10  end;
 11  /
l_id = 2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Shortly, I don't understand what you are doing. Try to follow my examples. If it still doesn't work, post your SQL*Plus session.